# video tag not displaying webrtc stream video with Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, html5-video, webrtc

xyz.html

`<video id="localVideo" #localVideo autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<video id="remoteVideo" #remoteVideo autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<button (click)="startVideoCall()">Start video call </button>`

xyz.ts

```
    @ViewChild ('localVideo') public localVideo:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild ('remoteVideo') public remoteVideo:ElementRef;

    //on getUserMedia
           this.localVideo.nativeElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    this.localVideo.nativeElement.play();

    // on receiving the remote stream
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.play();
```

I am using WebRTC for a video call application. The issue is i am able to see my local video. But the same doesnt work for remote video. When i do inspect element on remoteVideo video tag i can see the url. The enitre tag when i receive the remote stream is as follows : 
`<video _ngcontent-c7="" autoplay="autoplay" id="remoteVideo" src="blob:http://localhost:4200/832b72ca-4184-4215-9ab6-276242bf0291"></video>`
but the video is not visible. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way, to support both types:

```
try {

    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = event.stream;

} catch(error) {

    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
};

this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.play();
```